# Video generator for any audio

Tags: software-recommendation, video

I have some audio files. I want to make them available as YouTube videos. But I do not want a static image, like an album cover, appearing all the time. I want some "moving fractal images" video style (but in fact it could be any other "style"). Some media players have this visualization tool. But what I want is to have the video file (with the audio) to upload to YouTube.

**How** can I achieve this? Which **program(s)** should I use? Or which **commands** to type in the command line?

Comment: `Some media players have this visualization tool` which players? if you can give examples i might be able to do some research, btw i think this question fits more on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have `vlc` and `totem` installed. Both provide visualization. `vlc` output is not nice. `totem` output is great - if only I could save it in a video file...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a not so elegant way of doing it:

1. Install [RecordMyDesktop](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gtk-recordmydesktop/) from the Software Centre.
2. Fire up one of those programmes that produce the "moving images".
3. Record the "moving images" window with RecordMyDesktop (it also captures the sound).